# FadeIn&FadeOut object from another frameset

Tags: javascript, html, function, frameset, visual-web-developer

I would like to make a href that onclick activates a JS function that fades in and fades out 2 objects from another frameset, this is what I have so far(these codes have been taken from different places around the web and might be far off, I thank you if you can be kind enough to help me) -

FRAMESET A:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LogoToNews() {
    var LogoBot = window.frames["TopLogo"].document.getElementById("LogoBot");
    var LogoBotNews = window.frames["TopLogo"].document.getElementById("LogoBot_News");
    LogoBot.fadeTo("slow", 0)
    LogoBotNews.fadeTo("slow", 1.0)
} 
</script>
<a href="#" class="Normal" onclick="LogoToNews()">LinkHere</a>
```

FRAMESET B:

```
<LogoBot><img id="LogoBot"/></LogoBot>
<LogoBot_News><img id="LogoBot_News/></LogoBot_News>
```

My goal is the fade out LogoBot and fade in LogoBot_News using the href from Framset A.

Answer (score 0):

Raw DOM elements don't have a `fadeTo()` function.

If you want to use jQuery, you'll need to create a jQuery object:

```
$(window.frames["TopLogo"].document.getElementById("LogoBot"))
```

Or

```
$('#LogoBot', window.frames.TopLogo.document)
```

Comment: Did you mean to do it like this:

<script type="text/javascript">
    function LogoToNews() {
        $(window.frames["TopLogo"].document.getElementById("LogoBot")).fadeTo("slow", 0);
        $(window.frames["TopLogo"].document.getElementById("LogoBot_News")).fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
    } 
</script>

Comment: @user2719268: Yes; that will work, although you can make it shorter.

Comment: It doesn't really work for me yet... can you help me again i've added some more information to the question, could it be because the framesets are nested withing a bigger frameset ? ?